# Calculation using Integrate & Plot take too long time & some error

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I want to plot this equation.

[image]

***mu, Eb***, gamma, ***Eg*** are constant parameters and x is independent parameter.

```
\[Mu] := 1;
Eb := 0.040;
\[CapitalGamma] := 1;(*Fitting parameter*)
Eg := 2.354
Ebj := Eg - Eb/j^2
c := 1.4 (*fitting parameter*)
A[x_?NumericQ] := \[Mu]^2/x (Sum[(2 Eb /j^3 Sech[(x - Ebj)/\[CapitalGamma]]), {j, 1, 10}] + 
Integrate[Sech[(x - e)/\[CapitalGamma]] 1/(1 - c (e - Eg))(*1/(1-
 E[-2 Pi Sqrt[Eb/(e-Eg)]])*) , {e, Eg, 2.355}])

Plot[A[x], {x, 2.0, 3.5}]
```

There are two problem.

1. Above the equation, I omit **(*1/(1-E[-2 Pi Sqrt[Eb/(e-Eg)]])*)** part because of NIntegrate : non-numerical values error. (maybe divergence issue)
2. Although I omit some part, It takes too long time to Plot.

How remove that error and save calculation time?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Integral has no closed form solution, so use `NIntegrate` instead of `Integrate`:

```
\[Mu] := 1;
Eb := 0.040;
\[CapitalGamma] := 1;(*Fitting parameter*)Eg := 2.354
Ebj := Eg - Eb/j^2
c := 1.4 (*fitting parameter*)
```

and

```
A[x_?NumericQ] := \[Mu]^2/
   x (Sum[(2 Eb/j^3 Sech[(x - Ebj)/\[CapitalGamma]]), {j, 1, 10}] + 
    NIntegrate[Sech[(x - e)/\[CapitalGamma]] 1/(1 - c (e - Eg))(*1/(1-
     E[-2 Pi Sqrt[Eb/(e-Eg)]])*), {e, Eg, 2.355}])
```

then

```
Plot[A[x], {x, 2.0, 3.5}]
```

delivers:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. but when I input 1/(1 - E[-2 Pi Sqrt[Eb/(e - Eg)]]) part, the errors exist yet. (non-numerical values).  Is there any solution??

Comment: Could not try at the moment, but in the picture of your formula is no "-" before "2Pi..." product? Maybe a typo?

Comment: Oh... that image is wrong... and I found typo not E but Exp[...] thank you